# Debug Tornado Web Server in Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, tornado

Is there anyone who can debug the code run in Tornado Web Server in Pycharm?

I searched the question in google, but I can not found the answer.

Comment: Sure it works, I have used it quite frequently; just create a handler, add a breakpoint and make a request to see it in action.

Comment: Hello @IonutTicus, thank you for your reply. Can you share your Run/Debug configuration to run Tornado Web Server the Pycharm. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps I used:

- In your PyCharm project, create a new Python file called `tornado_test.py` and paste the contents of the [hello world example](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/#hello-world) on Tornado's docs.
- Right click on the newly created file and select `Debug 'tornado_test'`
- Create a breakpoint on line 13 ( `self.write("Hello, world")` ) using left-click next to the line number
- Open a browser and go to `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` (it should start waiting for a response)
- Go back to PyCharm and your breakpoint should be activated (you can now debug the code, see variables such as `request` for example)

Screenshot (don't worry about the blurred parts - those are just other files I had in my project):

[image]

Of course you need to have Tornado installed in the (virtual) Python environment you use in PyCharm.